# To add a different color using jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div id="autoSuggestedPlaces">

      <div>
           <div>

          </div>
      </div>

      <div>
           <div >

          </div>
      </div>

      <div>
           <div>

          </div>
      </div>


</div>
```

my html markup is lookes like this i want to add, i want to add even div have diffrent bacground color and odd div have diffrent color, I tried this but using div.even and div.odd but its not working.

Comment: why you have same ids 'addAPlaceSearchResult' ?

Comment: is your example 4 divs with bg color or 3? In other words is the parent div #1 or are you only considering the child divs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$("div#autoSuggestedPlaces div div:even").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
$("div#autoSuggestedPlaces div div:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

Comment: +1, although it might be preferable to simply add an even/odd class, and have that styled in the CSS. IMO, that enforces the separation of display from functionality *slightly* better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) and [`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)

`div.even` will select all div elements with class name `even`.

Also as pointed out by @Haim never use same id for multiple elements.

```
.first
{
    background-color: yourfirstcolor;
}


.second
{
    background-color: yoursecondcolor;
}

$("#autoSuggestedPlaces div:even").addClass("first");
$("#autoSuggestedPlaces div:odd").addClass("second");
```

Answer (score 0):

the code is like :

```
 $("div:odd").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
  $("div:even").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
```

and Using the same ID twice in the same document is not valid HTML. Fix your HTML.